# Passing multiple parameters by POST using ajax to php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to pass multiple parameters via the POST method using AJAX to my PHP file so that I can make a query to a MySQL database.

HTML file :

```
        <div class="dropdown dropdown-dark">
            <select  class="dropdown-select" id="searchselect11" required>

                        <option value="faculty">Faculty</option>
                        <option value="dept">Dept.</option>
                        <option value="course">Course</option>
                        <option value="year">Year</option>
                        <option value="name">Name</option>

            </select>
        </div> 


<td style="padding:5px;"> <input type="text" id="searchtext11" required></td>

<button id="searchgo1"  onclick="searchone()"></button>
```

This is the Javascript file where I successfully access dropdown value and textbox value and store them in `sv` and `searchtext11` variables respectively. But the problem is to pass the two values to the PHP file. The problem seems to be in `the_data` variable that is passed in `xmlhttp.send(the_data);`

The `searchone()` function is as follows:

```
function searchone()
{
//alert("hi");

var xmlhttp;
var sel = document.getElementById('searchselect11'); 
var sv = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
var searchtext11= document.getElementById("searchtext11").value;
var  the_data = 'select='+sv+'text='+searchtext11;


if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }




  xmlhttp.open("POST", "searchone.php", true);          
  xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            
  xmlhttp.send(the_data);       


  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
      document.getElementById("searchresults").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
}
```

This PHP code works only if

```
var the_data='select='+sv;
```

searchone.php

```
<?php   


if (isset($_POST['select'])) {
    $str = $_POST['select'];    // get data

    echo $str;
}
?>
```

How do i get both dropdown and textbox value to my PHP file so that i can form sql query using those variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use an ampersand, just as if it was a *GET*. Further, you should [**encode your text**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to make sure that it doesn't contain any characters that could have a special meaning

```
var the_data = ''
    + 'select=' + window.encodeURIComponent(sv)
    + '&text=' + window.encodeURIComponent(searchtext11);
//     ^                    ^^
```

You don't need to decode manually server-side because you are already letting it know that *POST* data is `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: I'd add that the `window` of `window.encodeURIComponent` is implicit and can be omitted...

Comment: Please also highlight whether should i use 

 `if (isset($_POST['select']))` or `if (isset($_POST['select'], $_POST['text']))

Comment: @akashaggarwaal I'd suggest checking both if you require both. @Basic `window` can be omitted in most cases, but when I use _methods_ of `window`, my style is to keep it. So, for example, I would use `window.setTimeout`, too.

Comment: encodeURIComponent() is usless here, because your parametrs are not URIs, string is enough

Comment: @vladkras what if the client types into the `<input>` a string like `"hello&somevar=iWin"`?

Comment: @vladkras but better the website doesn't break as I get around to it :P

Comment: that's why you need to prevent such efforts both on client and server side and not send them, even encoded. I've never seen an app where someone has to type such queries in input (maybe except search engines, but i'm not sure they use stackoverflow to solve smth)

Comment: thanx everyone for your inputs..helped a lot..
i successfully created the sql query also got the results but while displaying the results it gives a notice:



`Notice: Array to string conversion in E:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-12.1\www\university\site\searchone.php on line 21
Array`

Comment: $rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

       $nr = mysql_num_rows($rs);

       for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) {

        $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs);

        echo $r["];
       }

Comment: you have to use a key, e.g. echo $r[0]

Comment: also you'd better use `while($r = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) { //do what you need with $r array}` instead of `$nr = mysql_num_rows($rs); for ($i=0; $i<$nr; $i++) { $r = mysql_fetch_array($rs); echo $r["];`

Answer (score 5):

add & in this string:

```
var  the_data = 'select='+sv+'&text='+searchtext11;
```

Comment: @Rush.2707 any number of variables: `var data = 'var1='+var1+'&var2='+var2+'&var3='+var3+'... etc.` String length is limited only by [GET request length](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request) (~8Kb). Also, it's better is to use [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on every variable